# close dialog by clicking button - JQuery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I try to create a button that closes "dialog" window in JQuery UI.

To open the dialog i'm using this code:

```
$(".show .edit_site").click(function (){
    rel = $(this).attr("rel");

    $("#dialog_edit").dialog({
            modal: true,
            open: function () {
                $(this).load("<?= site_url()?>/sites/show_update?id="+rel+"&mode=popup");
            },
            close: function() {
                //some code
            },
            height: 370,
            width: 900,
            title: 'Some title'
     });
});
```

The dialog opened and everything is fine. 
But now the question is how do I close the dialog by clicking on the button that is inside the dialog?

[image]
Thank you all and sorry for my terrible English :)

---

I tried every possible solution, this the only one who works for me:

```
function close_dialog()
{
    //Close jQuery UI dialog 

    $(".ui-dialog").hide();
    $(".ui-widget-overlay").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 14):

It's simple, just add the button as part of the dialog's options:

```
$("#dialog_edit").dialog({
    modal: true,
    open: function () {
        $(this).load("<?= site_url()?>/sites/show_update?id="+rel+"&mode=popup");
    },
    height: 370,
    width: 900,
    title: 'Some title',
    buttons: {
        'button text' : function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use ['close'](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#method-close) method:

```
$("#dialog_edit").on('click', '#closeButtonId', function(){
     $(this).closest("#dialog_edit").dialog('close');
});
```

Comment: @roev You need to replace '`closeButtonId`' by appropriate id of your button. Have you done it ? What `id` or `class` your button has?

Comment: still not work.
It may be connected to the event line:
`$(".show .edit_site").click`
?

by the way, the click event in the popup is ok, only line that should close the popup not working.

Comment: @roev Do you have multiple elements with the same '`dialog_edit`' id?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14299/discussion-between-engineer-and-roev)

Answer (score -1):

I tried the below code and it worked

```
 $('#btnClose').click(function () {
     window.parent.jQuery('#msgbox').dialog('close');
 });
```